# Can I use multiple mutate if elses to build a sequential column (flagging for multiple issues)

Tags: r

I'm having trouble in R where I'm attempting to build a column progressively using multiple mutate statements with conditional if-else logic using the dplyr package. Specifically, I want to create a new column, called 'Issues', in my data frame based on various conditions applied to another column.

Each condition in the mutate statement checks if the row information to either add a description e.g. "Missing Address" to the 'Issues' column based on specific criteria. However, I'm having trouble achieving this sequential building of the 'Issues' column.

I've tried something like this:

```
  df <- data.frame(
    PreferredName  = "",
    FirstName = c("Mary", "Harold (Harry)", "Ben", "Tristian (Tri)", "Julia"),
    County = c("", "Other", "Warren", "Butler", ""),
    Date = as.Date(2024-02-15),
    Address = c("123 Street", "42 Ave", "", "", "520 Road")
  )

df_cor <- df %>%
  mutate(Issues = ifelse((PreferredName == "" & grepl("\\(", FirstName)), "Preferred Name", "")) %>%
  mutate(Issues = ifelse(((County == "USA" | County == "" | County == "Other" | County == "N/A" )& Date >= as.Date("2023-08-01")), c(Issues, "County"), Issues)) %>%
  mutate(Issues = ifelse((Address == "" & Date >= as.Date("2023-08-01")), c("Address", Issues), Issues))
```

Yet this doesn't work as intended. I get a blank column when there should be a subsequent issue flagged.

I would like to have a new column named Issues = c("Address", "Address" "Preferred Name", "Address", "Address" "Preferred Name", "Address") or something like that.

I would greatly appreciate any insights or alternative approaches (ideally using dyplr).

Comment: Could you edit your `df` to be reproducible, and **include your desired output**? Also, could you explicitly state the issues that would occur? What if there are multiple issue? Its unclear. Thanks and good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `paste0()` in your `ifelse()`. You can also use `%in%` instead of `|` for multiple 'or' matches. You can also add multiple statements to a single `mutate()`. Judging by what you are adding to the Issues column, I'm guessing you are wanting to identify problems so you can correct the respective columns? In the case of preferred name, it's possible to copy preferred name from FirstName to PreferredName. If this is the case, update your question to include what your end goal is and I will update my answer. If not, this solution will be fine.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
  PreferredName  = "",
  FirstName = c("Mary", "Harold (Harry)", "Ben", "Tristian (Tri)", "Julia"),
  County = c("", "Other", "Warren", "Butler", ""),
  Date = as.Date("2024-02-15"),
  Address = c("123 Street", "42 Ave", "", "", "520 Road")
)

df_cor <- df %>%
  mutate(Issues = ifelse((PreferredName == "" & grepl("\\(", FirstName)), 
                         "Preferred Name ", ""),
         Issues = ifelse(County %in% c("USA", "", "Other", "N/A") & 
                           Date >= as.Date("2023-08-01"), 
                         paste0(Issues, "County "), Issues),
         Issues = ifelse((Address == "" & Date >= as.Date("2023-08-01")), 
                         paste0("Address ", Issues), Issues),
         Issues = trimws(Issues))

df_cor
  PreferredName      FirstName County       Date    Address                 Issues
1                         Mary        2024-02-15 123 Street                 County
2               Harold (Harry)  Other 2024-02-15     42 Ave  Preferred Name County
3                          Ben Warren 2024-02-15                           Address
4               Tristian (Tri) Butler 2024-02-15            Address Preferred Name
5                        Julia        2024-02-15   520 Road                 County
```